# _ is undefined when using custom build lodash

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I want to use both `._get()` and `._find()` (findWhere from underscore) from lodash in my angular application. Because there are not default in a standard build I need to create a custom build.

Via the lodash cli I have runnend this command: `lodash include=get,find`. I have included the generated `lodash.custom.js` into my project.

But now I'm getting an

> ReferenceError: _ is not defined

error on the functions I want to use.

```
var matchedShopProduct = _.find($rootScope.currentShop.products, {_id: formattedProduct._id});

var value = _.get($scope.product.versions[i].modifiedProperties[0], property);
```

I think I missed something wile building the custom build, but I can't find what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding `exports=admin,global` in the command. 
So the full command is:

```
lodash exports=amd,global include=get,find
```